# SQL query: how can I get "id" of department in which employees receive the maximum salary?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I get `id` of department in which employees receive the maximum salary:

Employee table: **Empl** (`ID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, DeptId`)
Departments table:  **Dept** (`ID, City`)

rus (Вывести “id” подразделения, в котором сотрудники получают максимальную заработную плату.)

Comment: The kind of query you only write if you're in school, or when you're in BI and are unhappy with your salary. ;-)

Comment: Do you want the department that have the maximum average of salary per emploeyee?

Comment: @DavyJonesUA - mm?, I believe that that's exactly what I was asking

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Changed `SUM(Salary)` to `AVG(Salary)` based on comments on the question.

```
SELECT TOP 1 DeptId
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY DeptId
    ORDER BY AVG(Salary) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.*
FROM (SELECT DeptId, AVG(Salary) AvgSalary
      FROM Empl
      GROUP BY DeptId) A
INNER JOIN Dept B
ON A.DeptId = B.Id
ORDER BY AvgSalary DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the one single Department's ID where the highest single salary is paid:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DeptID
FROM dbo.Empl
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DepartmentId
FROM    Employee
WHERE   Salary = (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you mean max average salary of a department and not the single highest salary across all departments.

However it seems all you would have to do is use the following SQL functions
MAX function
AVG function

group by department ID and viola.

Thought I agree with the comments above, I will assume you are doing this for research ;-)

Comment: Joe's solution is probably the best one here, love that he ordered them as well :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
  from dept
 where id = ( select deptid
                from ( select max(avg_salary), deptid
                         from ( select deptid, avg(salary) as avg_salary
                                  from empl
                                 group by deptid )
                        group by deptid )
                     )
```

:-)